# Estimating beat frequency amplitude caused by non-synchronized downstream buck converters

Tags: power-supply, power

I was reading a TI app note “Synchronizing DC/DC Converters in a Power Tree” which showed how subharmonics appear on the input voltage line when it powers two buck converters with different switching frequencies. The subharmonic/beat frequency is the difference between the two switching frequencies, but what about the subharmonic amplitude?

My best guess is that it could be approximated as half the product of the ripple amplitudes you would expect from each converter by themselves (using load current, duty ratio, and capacitance on the input line). I’m only guessing this because this is the amplitude of the subharmonic sinusoid when multiplying two sinusoids of different frequencies, but I am not sure if that works in this case.

Can the beat frequency amplitude be estimated this way, or some other way which only requires hand calculation and basic information about the circuit?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is more complex since the signals are rectangular, not square (except maybe the 2.5 from 5 in the best condition). So it will probably depend on the effective input voltage. As a first approximation I think it would be good however